# Get different data from Django views in table

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have CBV like this:

```
class MyTableViews(TemplateView):
    template_name = "table.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tables'] = Table.objects.all()
        return context
```

And I have tables like this:

```
<table id="t_add_row" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in tables %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.address }}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="edit" data-target="#rowEditModal">x</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That table produce something like this:

```
|Header1|  Header2  |    Header3    | Edit  |
|   1   |   Name1   |   Address1    |   x   |
|   2   |   Name2   |   Address2    |   x   |
|   3   |   Name3   |   Address3    |   x   |
```

And I have modal form in same templates, that targeted from above table for ID=#rowEditModal:

```
<div class="modal-content" id="rowEditModal">

    {% for t in tables %}
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Header1:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="header1" value="{{ t.id }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Header2:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="header2" value="{{ t.name }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Header3:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="header3" value="{{ t.address }}">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btn-updaterow" class="btn">Update</button>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

But when I click Edit button (x) for **each row** then it display **same data** from 1st row only:

```
Header1:    1
Header2:    Name1
Header3:    Address1
```

How to get different data for each row?

Comment: It seems you need to get the item id (via JS) and make a new request via AJAX to retrieve the specific row, in order to  correctly populate the modal.

Comment: Look at your HTML source in your browser. You'll see that your modal has a whole bunch of divs with class "modal-body". Whereas you want multiple modals and target the correct one. You should move your loop outside the modal to create multiple modals, each with its own id (and in your buttons make sure the data-target uses the correct id).

Comment: @dirkgroten, You are right. By using {{ forloop.counter }} for data-target solved this.